# GridView crash on android api level 14 although manifest is set for api 11 and up

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gridview

I am testing my app. It works fine on my Samsung Galaxy S5 and on my LG with android 4.1.2. But when I try to test it on LG 4.0.4 (real device) or an a simulator of Nexus 5, it crashes due to the following stack trace. My manifest is set to minimum sdk 11. Below the stack trace, I am also showing my GridView code. Thanks for any help troubleshooting this.

**Stack Trace**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1028)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4677)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2072)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12603)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1044)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**GridView**

Besides the usual findViewById, the only particular code in the activity that contains the GridView is

```
myGridView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (myGridViewAdapter.getNumColumns() == 0) {
                    final int numColumns = 2;
                    if (numColumns > 0) {
                        final int columnWidth = myGridView.getWidth() / numColumns;// - mImageThumbSpacing;
                        myGridViewAdapter.setNumColumns(numColumns);
                        myGridViewAdapter.setItemHeight(columnWidth);
                        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView - numColumns set to " + numColumns);
                        }
                        if (Utils.hasJellyBean()) {
                            myGridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        } else {
                            myGridView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

Then inside the adapter in the method `getView`, I have this snippet

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // First check if this is the top row
        if (position < mNumColumns) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = new View(mContext);
            }
            // Set empty view with height of ActionBar
            convertView
                .setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mActionBarHeight));
            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: The exception and the code you have copied is not mapping. You can post you're activity, adapter and xml before that once clean and build

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
convertView.setLayoutParams(new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, mActionBarHeight));
```